# How to achieve auto logoff in php?

Tags: php

I need auto-logoff system in my application.

if user not using the application more than thirty minutes.they should log in again.

this is what i need.
lastAccessTime should be lesser than 30 minutes. if lastAccessTime exceeds than 30 minutes user should login again with their credentials.

(currently i auto log off using Lastaccesstime field in My user table (database) and compare lastaccesstime with current time for every page loads, I do not think this is right way.)

is their any way to achieve?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should specify the SESSION LIFETIME and just use the `$_SESSION` to see if a user is logged in:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',(60*30)); // 60 seconds times 30 = 30 minutes
```

Comment: Wouldn't that also log off an active user after 30mins?

Comment: No, each time an active user visits the page, the cookie gets reset.

Comment: No, each request resets the cookie, and thus restarts the timer.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using cookies to keep users logged in, simply set an adequate TTL for it.

For a 30 minute expiration time, on login set the cookie this way:

```
setcookie($COOKIE_NAME, $COOKIE_VALUE, time() + 60 * 30);
```

Alternatively, you could use `session_set_cookie_params`

```
session_set_cookie_params(60 * 30); // takes lifetime as first argument
```